# Starting a thread with the GUI (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

My GUI freezes whenever the run method in the thread is called, does anybody know why?

Main :

```
try {
        // Set System Look and Feel
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainFrame frame = new MainFrame(null, null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

run method from thread:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

actionListener that is supposed to start the thread:

```
private ActionListener btnStartListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        robot.run();
    }
};




public class RobotThread implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the `run()` method does not start a new thread. Assuming your `robot` reference refers to an instance of `Runnable` you need to call the following;

```
new Thread(robot).start();
```

Calling `start()` will start a new thread, and call the `run()` method on it. Currently your `run()` method is being run on the same thread it is called from (in your instance the event dispatch thread).

Comment: +1 for `run()` not starting a new thread - but with swing it's the event dispatch thread rather than the main thread and this is causing the UI to freeze.

Comment: Yes, robot refers to an instance of Runnable. I tried your answer but the code in the run() isn't getting executed now.

Comment: @user3742929 - Where have you defined the `Runnable` that `robot` refers to? Maybe your Runnable's `run()` method is not a valid override or something along those lines.

Comment: I just added your code to my IDE and used `new Thread(new RobotThread()).start();` and it ran fine. Are there any other details we're missing, such as where `robot` is declared and instantiated? That said, you should never use `while(true){}` without a call to `Thread.sleep(x);` inside because otherwise the while loop could use all available CPU resources and hold everything else up.

Comment: I copied new Thread(new RobotThread()).start(); and it suddenly worked, don't know what my error was. Thanks :)